# how to compare and count number of occurrences in two list of list?

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I have two different list of list, with different size (List A with size in range 1000 and list B with size in range 10,000).

```
A=[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 5],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 5],
 [0, 1, 6],
 [0, 1, 7],
 [0, 1, 8],
 [0, 1, 9],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 2]] 
B=[[1, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [4, 2, 2],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [0, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 3]]
```

I need to compare list with list B and find out how many times each element of A occur in B. For example I need to find out how many times [0,0,0] (first element of A) occur in B.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can the elements in list A or list B be repeated?
is [0,1,0] considered different than [0,0,1]?

Comment: List A dose not have any repeated element, but list B has. List A is sample space for probability event assume you have 3 dice with 0 to 5 dots on them so if you roll all 3 together you can get distribution like this [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,4],[0,0,5],[0,1,0],....]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
A = [[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 5],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 5],
 [0, 1, 6],
 [0, 1, 7],
 [0, 1, 8],
 [0, 1, 9],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 2]] 
B = [[1, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 1],
 [4, 2, 2],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [0, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 3]]
nums = []
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if i in B:
            nums.append(str(i))
nums_freq = {}
nums = list(dict.fromkeys(nums))
for i in nums:
    count = 0
    for j in B:
        if i == str(j):
            if i in nums_freq.keys():
                nums_freq[i] += 1
            else:
                nums_freq[i] = 1
```

Value for `num_freq`:

```
{'[0, 0, 0]': 2,
 '[0, 0, 1]': 1,
 '[0, 0, 2]': 1,
 '[0, 1, 2]': 1,
 '[0, 1, 3]': 2,
 '[0, 2, 0]': 1,
 '[0, 2, 1]': 2}
```

Comment: No it dose not work. for example in above example there are 2 [0,0,0] in B but it just count one of them. Also I need to keep those that have frequency zero.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what you meant. I think I get it now. I edited my answer. Does it work like you want it to?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still dose not keep those with frequency zero. Answer must be entre list A with the number of occurrences in front of each elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import operator
>>> for e in A:
...     print(e, 'appearing in :',  operator.countOf(B, e))
...
[0, 0, 0] appearing in : 2
[0, 0, 1] appearing in : 1
[0, 0, 2] appearing in : 1
[0, 0, 3] appearing in : 0
[0, 0, 4] appearing in : 0
[0, 0, 5] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 0] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 1] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 2] appearing in : 1
[0, 1, 3] appearing in : 2
[0, 1, 4] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 5] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 6] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 7] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 8] appearing in : 0
[0, 1, 9] appearing in : 0
[0, 2, 0] appearing in : 1
[0, 2, 1] appearing in : 2
[0, 2, 2] appearing in : 0
```

Comment: This is an excellent package to compare two lists!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest 2 different ways to do it:

Using a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
cb = Counter(tuple(b) for b in B)
list((a, cb[tuple(a)]) for a in A))
```

Using nested comprehensions:

```
list((a, sum(all(ia == ib for ia, ib in zip(a, b)) for b in B)) for a in A)
```

---

Actually, you should consider having the inner collection as tuples instead of lists, because tuples support element-wise equality and are hashable.

if A and B were lists of tuples, it would be as simple as:

```
Counter(a for a in A for b in B if a == b)
```